# summing column in SQL from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I'm using MySQL and trying to sum the number of hours that user has participated in events, but only for a specific organization.

EDIT: I have another table thrown into the mix (misEvents). I think the GROUP BY statement is causing some problems, but I'm not quite sure what to do about it.

```
table events: contains the "event" information. orgID is the ID of the organization hosting it
-each listing is a separate event

ID | orgID | hours
1  |   1   |   1
2  |   1   |   2
3  |   2   |   1

table eventUserInfo: shows which users attended the events
-refID references the ID column from the events table

ID | refID | userID
 1 |   1   |   1
 2 |   1   |   3
 3 |   2   |   2
 4 |   2   |   1 
 5 |   3   |   2

table miscEvents
-these are entered in manually if an event by an organization wasn't posted on the site, but
the users still wants to keep track of the hours

ID |  userID  | orgID |  Hours
1  |    1     |  1    |    2
```

So, when I view the member activity for organization 1, the following table should display

```
userid | total hours
  1    |      5      //participated in ID #1 and 2 and a misc event, total of 4 hours
  2    |      2      //participated in ID #2 only for org 1
  3    |      1      //participated only in ID #1
```

assume the given input is $orgID which is set to 1 in this case

```
SELECT eventUserInfo.userID, sum(events.hours) as hours,sum(miscEvents.hours) AS mhours FROM events 
JOIN eventUserInfo ON events.ID = eventUserInfo.refID 
JOIN miscEvents ON events.orgID = miscEvents.orgID
WHERE events.orgID = '$orgID'
GROUP BY eventUserInfo.userID
```

Comment: You have a `JOIN` in there but I see no additional table that you are actually joining with the `events` table?

Comment: Shouldn't `userid=1` have 3 hours?

Comment: Yes to both of you. Typos on my part, I fixed them.

Comment: Maybe another typo: `SELECT event.userID,` shouldn't that be `events.userID`?

Comment: @JT Smith Fixed. I tried to copy/paste but it wouldn't format properly so I typed it out. I apologize for the typos, I think I caught them all.

Comment: Ok, just wasn't sure if it was copy/paste and the typo's were in your query

Comment: How is it "not working properly"? Giving error? Not correct results?

Comment: @ypercube the userID's are being displayed, but not the hours. I updated my original post to include how I'm attempting to output it.

Comment: @user1104854: You are trying to print the "hours" with: `$event['hours']`. Use an alias in the query, as in my edit.

Comment: Don't update the question if the problem is solved. Post a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
SELECT eventInfo.userID               --- there is no "events.userID" column
     , SUM(events.hours) AS hours     --- alias added
FROM events 
  JOIN eventInfo                      --- no need for LEFT JOIN
    ON events.ID = eventInfo.refID    
WHERE events.orgID = '$orgID'
GROUP BY eventInfo.userID
```

The problem lies probably in that you are trying to print the `"hours"` with: `$event['hours']` but there is no `hours` column returned (only `userID` and `SUM(event.hours)`. Use an alias in the `SELECT` list, as above.

Comment: I had a couple typos but I think I got all of them.

Comment: Got it to work. I think it was mainly the alias that was preventing me

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the help yesterday. That worked, but I actually have another table thrown in now. Could you possibly take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Or since eventINFO seems to be you primary table in the query:

```
SELECT eventINFO.userID, SUM(events.hours)
FROM eventINFO
JOIN events ON eventINFO.refID = events.ID
WHERE events.orgID = '$orgID'
GROUP BY eventINFO.userID
```

Should result in the same as ypercube but to me seems a little more clear calling your primary table in the `FROM` call

Comment: Thanks for the help yesterday, but I updated my post. I have another table thrown in and I can't seem to figure out this one now.

Answer (score 1):

To your new problem, you need to get rid of this:

```
sum(events.hours + miscEvents.hours)
```

If I'm not mistaken, you can't have multiple columns in a `SUM` you can only add a single column per call.

I would try something like:

```
SUM(events.hours) AS hours, SUM(miscEvents.hours) AS mhours
```

Then, in your function, add together those values `$total = hours + mhours`

Comment: However, to be fair to ypercube you shouldn't retract his accepted answer.  We are all here to help, in hopes of getting rep in return.  You should re-accept his answer, then post another question.  If you do this, let me know and I will post my new answer on your new question.

Comment: You're right JT. I figured if I posted again it would be removed because it's essentially the same question with one more condition. I  see what you did JT, however I think the issue lies with the GROUP BY statement. I could be way off, but it seems like that's giving me some trouble. I did update my code to reflect what you've done

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query now.... Show us the function that utilizes this query